# Why does my 'while p1 !=...' loop never stop

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, user-input

```
def outcome(p1, p2):
    x = ''
    if p1 == p2:
        x = 0
        return x
    elif p1 == "rock" and p2 == "scissors" or p1 == "scissors" and p2 == "paper" or p1 == "paper" and p2 == "rock":
        x = 1
        return x
    elif p2 == "rock" and p1 == "scissors" or p2 == "scissors" and p1 == "paper" or p2 == "paper" and p1 == "rock":
        x = 2
        return x

a = 0
while a == 1:
    p1 = str(input("P1 choose: "))
    while p1 != "rock" or  p1 != "paper" or p1 != "scissors":
        p1 = str(input("Please select rock/paper/scissors: "))
    p2 = str(input("P2 choose: "))
    while p2 != "rock" or  p2 != "paper" or p2 != "scissors":
        p2 = str(input("Please select rock/paper/scissors: "))
    b = outcome(p1, p2)
    if b == 1:
        print("P1 wins\n")
    elif b == 2:
        print("P2 wins\n")
    elif b == 0:
        print("Tied\n")
    pit = str(input("Another one? yes/no - "))
    if pit == "no":
        a = 0
        raise SystemExit(0)
```

This part never stops:

```
while p1 != "rock" or  p1 != "paper" or p1 != "scissors":
        p1 = str(input("Please select rock/paper/scissors: "))
```

This is a rock paper scissors game, and when I type in correctly or incorrectly it doesnt work and keeps repeating. I want it to repeat until you write either rock, paper, or scissors, and when you do write one of those, to exit the while loop.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `a = 1` to enter the loop in the first place? And you have to connect p!= with `and`, not `or`. Having said this - make a list and test, if your input is in this list.

Comment: Think a little bit more about that condition... If `p1` is equal to `"rock"` then `p1 != "rock"` will be `False`. But then `p1 != "paper"` automatically be `True`, which means the whole condition is `True`.

Comment: You can step through this loop manually on a piece of paper and see that its logic is flawed.

Answer (score 1):

```
while p1 != "rock" or  p1 != "paper" or p1 != "scissors":
    p1 = str(input("Please select rock/paper/scissors: "))
```

It says: `p` may be anything but `rock`, `paper`, `scissors`. If `p` equals any of these words, the whole predicate becomes `True`, and the loop continues. While applying the [De Morgan transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), you mistook `or` for `and`. The loop cannot be exited, because no `p` can simultaneously equal `rock`, `paper`, *and* `scissors`.

What you seemed to want is

```
while True:
  word = input("Please select rock/paper/scissors: ")  # it's already a string.
  if word in ("rock", "paper", "scissors"):
    break
```

Comment: This seems like very redundant coding.

Answer (score 1):

You should rewrite your condition:

```
while not (p1 == "rock" or p1 == "paper" or p1 == "scissors"):
    p1 = str(input("Please select rock/paper/scissors: "))
```

if one condition is correct, you exit the white loop.

Comment: The second part of your answer is not true: `if a and b or c and d or e and f` is actually the same as `if (a and b) or (c and d) or (e and f)`.

Comment: Right. And this is not the first time I got wrong on this.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are true, but a more pythonic way is to make a list (or tuple) of the acceptable inputs, and then check if the response is in it:

```
valids = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
while p1 not in valids:
    p1 = str(input("Please select rock / paper / scissors: "))
```

As you write more complex programs, this scales well: instead of a simple list, perhaps you use a function call on the argument, and in your input validation function, you perform any number of tests, etc, on the value.